# Grep ffmpeg time/duration to get progress stream?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, grep, progress

Is there a way to grep ffmpeg's unfriendly output to get the progress (time/duration) into a variable? I've tried this on powershell already but i can't get seem to get a hold of ffmpeg's  continuous output via pipe redirection and using the `--line-buffered` flag in grep.

Here is what I came up with but it only returns after the encoding process has finished.

`ffmpeg -i $input $output 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -oP "(?<=time=)[0-9:]*"`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is poster has made no attempt to solve the problem himself.

Comment: I've added what I did previously.

Answer (score 1):

This could get you started

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -v 0 -stats out.mp4 |& awk '{print $10}' RS='\r' FS='[ =]+'
```